# "Flow control statements are not properly nested." error while using Cmake for building OpenCV

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, cmake

I am trying to build OpenCV 3.2.0 on my Arch Linux laptop. I got the error when I run cmake.

The cmake command:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..
```

The full output:

```
CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:22 (cmake_minimum_required):
  Compatibility with CMake < 2.8.12 will be removed from a future version of
  CMake.

  Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
  CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.


CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:72 (cmake_policy):
  The OLD behavior for policy CMP0020 will be removed from a future version
  of CMake.

  The cmake-policies(7) manual explains that the OLD behaviors of all
  policies are deprecated and that a policy should be set to OLD only under
  specific short-term circumstances.  Projects should be ported to the NEW
  behavior and not rely on setting a policy to OLD.


CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:76 (cmake_policy):
  The OLD behavior for policy CMP0022 will be removed from a future version
  of CMake.

  The cmake-policies(7) manual explains that the OLD behaviors of all
  policies are deprecated and that a policy should be set to OLD only under
  specific short-term circumstances.  Projects should be ported to the NEW
  behavior and not rely on setting a policy to OLD.


CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:81 (cmake_policy):
  The OLD behavior for policy CMP0026 will be removed from a future version
  of CMake.

  The cmake-policies(7) manual explains that the OLD behaviors of all
  policies are deprecated and that a policy should be set to OLD only under
  specific short-term circumstances.  Projects should be ported to the NEW
  behavior and not rely on setting a policy to OLD.


-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 12.2.1
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 12.2.1
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detected version of GNU GCC: 122 (1202)
CMake Error at cmake/OpenCVCompilerOptions.cmake:21 (else):
  Flow control statements are not properly nested.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:495 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Should I need to change Cmake file? I am expecting it shouild work without modifying cmake file or something in code folder.

Comment: The `else` statement on the line 21 is actually misplaced in version 3.2.0: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/3.2.0/cmake/OpenCVCompilerOptions.cmake#L21. You may try to build newer OpenCV.

Comment: I removed it and tried again but this time i got "ISO C++17 forbids..." errors when compiling source. So I grab 3.4 version from aur. Thanks.